# In R, using binomial() and lapply to constrain predict() values between 0 and 1

Tags: r, lapply, glm, predict

I have a GLM, family=binomial(link=logit) model that I apply within a predict() function, seen below.  The predict values go beyond zero and 1, but I would like to keep them as probabilities. So I use the binomial()$inverse command that can be then be used in the apply function.

This worked just fine the first time I ran it, but after closing R down and starting again, I now get this error:

```
     Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
     object 'ilogit' of mode 'function' was not found"
```

I've been struggling with this for hours, as this code normally worked.  Does anyone have an idea about what I am doing wrong?  Is there a better way of doing this?

My code is below.  I've also tried other variation but can't get it to work.

```
    ## predicted probabilities 
    pp <- predict(logit_model,
            newdata=data,
            type="link",
            se.fit=T)

   ilogit <- binomial()$inverse
   yhat_prob <- lapply(pp,ilogit) #converts to probabilities
```

Comment: Use `type="response"` in your `predict` call to get the probabilities

Comment: Thanks James, but unfortunately, the type "response" does not get the values I need.  If I can get the ilogit object to work, then I can get the correct estimates...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the probabilities, you can have them directly with `type="response"`, as explained in the documentation, `?pregict.glm`.

For the error message you get, you probably need `binomial()$linkinv`.

```
> str( binomial() )
List of 12
 $ family    : chr "binomial"
 $ link      : chr "logit"
 $ linkfun   :function (mu)  
 $ linkinv   :function (eta)  
 $ variance  :function (mu)  
 ...
```

The lack of error was probably due to some package you had loaded, which defined an `ilogit` function.

Comment: Thanks Vincent.  Yes, I went down this path earlier,and this does get me probabilities directly.  But the ilogit/lapply function gave me nice parametric plots.  With linkinv or response, I get jagged plots that don't look right using the yhat_prob$fit. I had it working this morning; this is really frustrating!

Comment: ahhh, I got it working!  I'll give you the check for the detailed response, and also I think you were right about the ilogit function.  It is part of the faraway package, which I had on this morning.

Comment: For future reference, you can also use `plogis` on the linear predictor to get the inverse logit transform, without having to make an `ilogit` function.

Comment: Note also that back-transforming the standard errors is likely to give you gibberish.